# Circular dependency libwebp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, libwebsockets

trying to fix and old ios application which made by objective-c. However, whenever I try to `$ pod install` it gives that dependency error below and I couldn't find anything about it.

```
Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.    
Analyzing dependencies
There is a circular dependency between libwebp/utils and libwebp/dsp
```

ps: this is first time working with an app sorry about it.

Comment: Please provide all _relevant_ information to be able to help. Podfile ...

Comment: 1. What is your concrete Q? "Why is this not working" is no Q at SO. 2. did you google about circular references?